# Socket programming python.Unable to return response from one function to other

Tags: python

I am writing a simple socket program that connects to a remote sevrer.I recieve a response from the server and attempt tos end it to another function by calling it inside that ffunction.however when I print that response  I get nothing
Here is the code:

```
def Sendcm(self,command):



         result ="ok"
         try:
             #print "start"
             if command.startswith("#"):
               #print result
               return result

             elif not command:
                 return result

            # print 'yes'
             result=self.sendWait(command)
             print ('This is::')
             print result \\blank
         except Exception as e:
             traceback.print_exc()

         return result
```

sendWait function

```
 def sendWait(self,cmd):


          try:


               b=len(cmd)

               s.send(struct.pack("!H",b))
               s.send(cmd)
               response=s.recv(1024)

               print "The response received is:::"
               print response
               if RESP_OK in response:
                    return
               elif RESP_SUCCESS in response:
                    return
               elif RESP_Failure in response:
                    return

               return response 
          except Exception:
               traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: `s.send(struct.pack("!H",b))` ... what is `s` here?

Comment: s is a socket that I created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.The problem is the return statement inside the if statements.Due to this the code never returns the response.i put the whole code inside a while loop and use break to break out of the loop and return the response.Now it's working fine
The changes:

```
while True:

                    s.send(cmd)
                    response=s.recv(1024)

                    print "The response received is:::"
                    print response
                    if RESP_OK in response:
                         break
                    elif RESP_SUCCESS in response:
                         break
                    elif RESP_FAILURE in response:
                         break

               return response
```